# Rocky Linux 9, NFS mount issues to ESXi hosts after conversions from Centos, NFS-Common is listed

Tags: centos, mount, nfs, vmware

Rocky Linux 9.2

```
[root@mediastore8 nfs]# uname -r
5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64
```

I have upgraded/converted this box from a long running Centos system.

No hardware or other environment changes.

I have 3 x ESXi hosts that mount an NFS share from this host and have done so under Centos for the last couple of years with no issues.

I have uninstalled RPCBind, NFS-Utils from the box, rebooted and reinstalled but still am not able to get the NFS services to run and present the shares.

Here is the share defintion

```
[root@mediastore8 nfs]# cat /etc/exports
/Storage/Virtual-Machines       192.168.202.0/255.255.255.0(async,rw,no_root_squash,insecure)
/Storage/Virtual-Machines       172.16.200.0/255.255.255.0(async,rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure)
/Storage/Virtual-Machines       172.16.100.0/255.255.255.0(async,rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure)
/Storage/Virtual-Machines       192.168.86.0/255.255.255.0(async,rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure)
```

The last two entries have been added for troubleshooting purposes.

The linux firewall is disabled on this system (again part of the troubleshooting)

When i run

```
[root@mediastore8 nfs]# systemctl status -l rpcbind
● rpcbind.service - RPC Bind
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-13 15:35:55 AEST; 18h ago
TriggeredBy: ● rpcbind.socket
       Docs: man:rpcbind(8)
   Main PID: 1222 (rpcbind)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 95804)
     Memory: 2.6M
        CPU: 71ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
             └─1222 /usr/bin/rpcbind -w -f

Sep 13 15:35:55 mediastore8.curtin.home systemd[1]: Starting RPC Bind...
Sep 13 15:35:55 mediastore8.curtin.home systemd[1]: Started RPC Bind.
```

and when i run

```
[root@mediastore8 nfs]# systemctl status -l nfs-server
○ nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
             └─order-with-mounts.conf

 Active: inactive (dead)
```

Any ideas of what i can try to get this back and running ?

Craig

Answers to some of the questions (thanks Steven Harris)

`rpcinfo -p`

'program vers proto   port  service     100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper     100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper     100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper     100000    4   udp    111  portmapper     100000    3   udp    111  portmapper     100000    2   udp    111  portmapper'

```
showmount -e
```

`clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered`

OK following some more of the suggestions on here and the Rocky Linux forums - the issue was that even though NFS-Utils and RPCbind were uninstalled prior to the upgrade - they had left behind symbolic links in the /etc/systemd/system directory. These symbolic links were looking for the nfs-convert service and were being activated each time the products were reinstalled - as noted below this nfs-convert service no longer exists.

After deleting the symlinks, then reinstalling

rpcbind and nfs-utils

and then going through the systemctl enable and systemctl start process all is now working.

Thanks for the all hints and suggestions

Craig

Comment: You should be able to verify the RPC services are running with `rpcinfo -p` and verify the exports with `showmount -e`.   If they both look good then have you verified the _firewall_ configuration is allowing NFS access?   You can check that by turning it off (`systemctl stop firewalld`).  I know you said it's off, but you can verify ;-)

Comment: Are there any errors when you try to start `nfs-server`?

Comment: When i try to start the NFS server i get this message `systemctl start rpcbind
[root@mediastore8 nfs]# systemctl start nfs-server
Failed to start nfs-server.service: Unit nfs-convert.service not found.
`

Comment: You should edit your question to add these outputs, rather than have them in comments.

Comment: The error message states: `Unit nfs-convert.service not found`. That daemon doesn't exist on Rocky Linux 9. or Alma Linux 9 or the OS from which Rocky was forked, RHEL 9. `nfs-convert.service` was provided by `nfs-utils 2.3.3` which was the the version for Rocky Linux 8 (and also CentOS 8) whereas Rocky Linux 9 has `nfs-utils 2.5.4` which no longer has it. The `nfs-server.service` that you have installed is still looking for `nfs-convert.service` for some reason. Add the output of `rpm -qa | grep nfs-utils` and `tail -f /var/log/messages` while starting `nfs-server` to the question.